# How To assign keyboard shortcut to a new application in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, settings, terminator

I am using ubuntu 13.10. I installed Terminator(Terminal emulator) and after that uninstalled Terminal now i want to assign ALT+CTRL+T keyboard shortcut to the above said application. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut Tab -> Launchers -> left click Terminal -> press backspace.

Custom Shortcuts -> left click the plus sign at the bottom -> type a name for the shortcut and the BASH (terminal) command to launch Terminator -> left click the shortcut and press ALT+CTRL+T.

Comment: what will be the bash command for terminator(terminal emulator)

Comment: "terminator"  -I think, I don't have it installed to check.

Comment: i found the bash command but after creating new shortcut it's showing its status as disabled neither left nor right click is helping me to make the change i am not able to add ALT+CTRL+T by pressing the same buttons from the keyboard.

Comment: left click where it says "disabled", that should allow you to put in a new shortcut. Clicking elsewhere where just open the window to edit the shortcut command.